# solving an equation $\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}h(n)\mathrm{sin}[(n-\alpha)\omega+\beta]=0$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

If we have the equation:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}h(n)\mathrm{sin}[(n-\alpha)\omega+\beta]=0.$$

We want to solve for the combination of $(h,\alpha,\beta)$ that this equation holds for all $\omega\in \mathbb{R}$.

Here, $h:=h(n)$ is a real valued finite sequence, $\alpha,\beta $ are real valued constants to be solved. Of course, we are not interested in the trivial case in which $h(n)\equiv0$.

Can you find the other solutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sinus functions for pairwise different frequencies are linearly independent. There is only the trivial linear combination that combines to zero.

Comment: Not really. Consider the case: $h(n)=h(2\alpha-n), \beta=0$ where $2\alpha$ is a positive integer. In other words, the $h(n)$ can be paired and the sine of them have different signs, so the sum is zero. But I want an elegant proof of all the possible solutions. :-)